# GCE Service Account with Compute Instance Admin permissions

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-iam

I have setup a compute instance called to run cronjobs on Google Compute engine using a service account with the following roles: 

`Custom Compute Image User + Deletion rights
Compute Admin
Compute Instance Admin (beta)
Kubernetes Engine Developer
Logs Writer
Logs Viewer
Pub/Sub Editor
Source Repository Reader
Storage Admin`

Unfortunately, when I ssh into this cronjob runner instance and then run:

```
sudo gcloud compute --project  {REDACTED} instances create e-latest \
    --zone {REDACTED} --machine-type n1-highmem-8 --subnet default \
    --maintenance-policy TERMINATE  \
    --scopes  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform \
    --boot-disk-size 200  \
    --boot-disk-type pd-standard --boot-disk-device-name e-latest \
    --image {REDACTED} --image-project {REDACTED} \
    --service-account NAME_OF_SERVICE_ACCOUNT \ 
    --accelerator type=nvidia-tesla-p100,count=1 --min-cpu-platform Automatic
```

I get the following error:

> The user does not have access to service account {NAME_OF_SERVICE_ACCOUNT}.  User: {NAME_OF_SERVICE_ACCOUNT} .  Ask a project owner to grant you the iam.serviceAccountUser role on the service account.

Is there some other privilege besides compute instance admin that I need  to be able to create instances with my instance?

Further notes: (1) when I try to not specify `--service-account` the error is the same except that the service account my user doesn't have access to is the default '51958873628-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com'.
(2) adding/removing sudo doesn't change anything

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creating an instance that uses a service account requires you have the compute.instances.setServiceAccount permission on that service account.  To make this work, grant the [iam.serviceAccountUser](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#the_serviceaccountuser_role) role to your service account (either on the entire project or on the specific service account you want to be able to create instances with).

Comment: I think the confusing thing is that the error states that you need to add the role to the service account, when in fact you need to add it to the user.  A role is just a collection of permissions that your user gets when you assign that role.  The actual permission that is missing is something like iam.serviceAccounts.actAs which can be assigned to your user without a filter condition (all SA in the project) or with a filter (access to act as a specific SA only)

Answer (score 6):

#### Find out who you are first

If you are using local `gcloud` or `terraform`: find the json file that contains your credentials (often named similarly to  `myproject*.json`) and:

1. See if it contains the **project_id**: `grep project_id  myproject*.json`
2. See if it contains the **email**: `grep client_email  myproject*.json`

#### GCP IAM change

1. Go to https://console.cloud.google.com
2. On top of the page, select the project matching **project_id**
3. Go to IAM & Admin then -> IAM
4. Find the same **email** address
5. Edit principal -> Add Another Role -> type in the role name: `Service Account User` -> click Add

(You can narrow it down with a Condition, but lets keep it simple for a while).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that NAME_OF_SERVICE_ACCOUNT is service account from current project.

If you change project ID, and don't change NAME_OF_SERVICE_ACCOUNT, then you will encounter this error.

This can be checked on Google Console -> IAM & Admin -> IAM.
Then look for service name ....-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com and check if numbers at the beginning are correct. Each project will have different numbers in this service name.